# Cannot convert value of type '(Receiver) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> (Void) -> ()'

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming, swift4

Implemented an `Event` type in Swift, reminiscent of C#, based on [this](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/05/swift-events.html) article.

After converting to Swift 4, the following code no longer compiles:

```
class Receiver {
    func doIt() {

    }
}

class Sender {
    let event = Event<Void>()
}

let sender = Sender()
let receiver = Receiver()

sender.event.addHandler(target: receiver, handler: Receiver.doIt)
```

Error:
`Cannot convert value of type '(Receiver) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> (Void) -> ()'`

Definition of `addHandler`:

```
public func addHandler<Target: AnyObject>(target: Target,
         handler: @escaping (Target) -> (DataType) -> ())
```

The error is fixed if I change the method to `doIt(_ a: Void)` -- but this seems a bit redundant.

Is there a change added in Swift 4 that breaks the old behaviour?